# Automatically Selecting File and Submitting, Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to programmatically browse and I want to upload a file to an input tag with the type of file.

How would I go about this? I don't want the user to have to input any data, but to instead go after a predefined file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is NOT possible since it would be a real security flaw - see http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#file-select

Comment: I would really appreciate a sudo function for browsers. Like "Hey user, this is dangerous, unstable and likely to harm your security." - "I don't care, just do it. I'm fine with the consequences"

Answer (score 1):

You can't have your script browse the user's machine and automatically search for a file you think they want to submit - but you can have your form submit when they find the file they want to give you:

`<input type="file" name="my_file" />`

That will generate a "Browse" button next to the field which, when the user clicks it, will open an OS explorer window to select their file.

Example form:

```
<form name="form" id="my_form">
    <input type="file" id="my_file" name="my_file" />
</form>
```

From there, simply place an onchange event listener on the field to automatically submit your form. With JQuery it looks like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#my_file').change(function(){
       $('#my_form').submit();
    }); 

    $('#my_form').submit(function(event){
        alert('form submitted');
    });
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/SZFfL/

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.  For `<input type=file>`, the `value` attribute of the input element is READONLY with Javascript.  Otherwise, that would be a large security hole.